# Typo3 Breadcrumb with stdWrap.data possible?

Tags: typo3

I am new to Typo3 and wanted to have something like this: date / page1 > page2 > page3...

I know how to make a simple breadcrumb but now I wonder how I can put the current date in front of it. When I try the stdWrap.data + stdWrap.dataWrap the breadcrumb doesn't show.

```
20 = HMENU
20 {
    special = rootline
    special.range = 0 | -1
    stdWrap.data = date : d.m.Y ::: 
    stdWrap.dataWrap =  <p> | </p>
    //wrap = <p> | </p>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = | &nbsp; > &nbsp;
        CUR = 1
        CUR.allWrap = |
    }
}
```

Currently I don't know if I had to write to objects in typoscript for it or if I could do it in once like I tried. Maybe you can hint me to something or explain a simple way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a proper wrapping.

```
20.stdWrap.data
```

is no wrap at all and will be ignored so you might only get an empty `p`-tag from the `stdWrap.dataWrap`.

Following your attempt I think you want something like:

```
20.dataWrap = <p>{date:d.m.Y}</p> |
```

so I don't get it why you use a `p` tag to get all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a different TypoScript:

```
lib.breadcrumb = COA
lib.breadcrumb {
  stdWrap.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    wrap = <li>|</li>
    data = date : U
    strftime = %A, %e. %B %Y
  }

  20 = HMENU
  20 ... your TS for the breadcrumb menu
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Ok I could set the two list items beside each other, but the thing is that I have a text object before the date/breadcrumb. So all would be on one line if I don't do some css and that's not my intention. Is there a possibility where I can just wrap something around object 20 and 30 and let 10 alone?